# Finding extreme points of linear programming problem in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have the following linear programming problem:

max $z = 2x+4y$

subject to:

$5x + 3y + 5z \leq 15$

$10x + 8y + 15z \leq 40$

$x,y,z \geq 0$

I plotted the two lines in 3 dimensions but I am having trouble seeing where the extreme points would lie. Is there an algebraic way to find them?

Comment: Do you know simplex algorithm?

Comment: not yet, I just wanted to find the extreme points

Comment: Siong Thye Goh's guide is quite pedagogic in this case.

Comment: @GNUSupporter But it is not an efficient method of solving this problem graphically. I would call it naive method.

Comment: I changed the (mathematical meaning of the) question so that it matches the existing solutions.

Comment: @GNUSupporter And I mentioned that it can be done my the simplex algorithm. But the OP had problems with the graphical method. But there is no problem if you have a 2D problem.

Comment: @callculus You're right to mention simplex algorithm, which consists in selecting the basic variables in Siong Thye Goh's guide (or annulating some variables in my answer), but why do you [use MathJax for text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27542/290189)?

Comment: @GNUSupporter I have used MathJax to make the text a little bit smaller.

Comment: @callculus I see your point.  I would prefer boldface though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the $z$ variable has to be removed from the constraints. It can be substituted by $2x+4y$. Thus the problem becomes

> max $z = 2x+4y$
>
> subject to:
>
> $15x + 23y \leq 15$
>
> $40x + 68y \leq 40$
>
> $x,y \geq 0$
>
> $\small{\text{This problem is related to the original problem}}$

This problem can be solved $\textrm{graphically}$ ($2D$) or by applying the $\textrm{simplex algorithm}$.

Comment: Sorry I did not properly label the variables, I have edited the question. Is it still possible to ignore $x_3$?

Comment: @user1775500 More or less. Just set $x_3=0$. $x_3$ has no impact on the objective function. So you still have a problem with two variables which can be solved graphically. Do you know how this works?

Comment: I know that the graphical way in efficient in dimension two, but OP asks for an algebraic method.

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

- Vertices and basic feasible solution are equivalent.
- You have $5$ inequalities , pick $3$ of them, set them to equality and solve them as a linear system. If the solution is unique and it doesn't violate the other $2$ equalities (that is it is a feasible point), then it is an extreme point.

Remark:

In general, we do not enumerate all extreme point to solve a linear program, simplex algorithm is a famous algorithm to solve a linear programming problem. In general, number of vertices is exponential and though in theory, the worst case complexity of simplex method can be to visit every vertices, this is rarely the case in practice. Interior point method exists to solve linear programming problem too.

Comment: For the second bullet, what it means if the solution is not unique and doesn't violate the other 2 equalities ?

Comment: In that case, you haven't pin point an extreme point. Try another set of 3 inequalities

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the simplex algorithm, add slack variables $s,t \ge
0$ to the original problem
\begin{align}
5x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3 &\leq 15 \tag{$P_1$} \\
10x_1 + 8x_2 + 15x_3 &\leq 40 \tag{$P_2$}
\end{align}
so that the two constraints (which represent the image under two
planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$ in the first octant) becomes equalities.
\begin{align}
5x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3 + s &= 15 \tag{$E_1$} \\
10x_1 + 8x_2 + 15x_3 + t &= 40 \tag{$E_2$}
\end{align}
Since the objective function $z = 2x_1+4x_2$ has positive coefficients for
$x_1$ and $x_2$, it's normal to set $x_3 = s = t = 0$, so that
\begin{cases}
5x_1 + 3x_2 &= 15\\
10x_1 + 8x_2 &= 40.
\end{cases}
Solving this so that $2x_2 = 10 \iff x_2 = 5$ and $x_1 = (15-3(5))/5 = 0$.
So the maximum value is $z = 2(0) + 4(5) = 20$ when $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 =
5$.

Comment: Finding extreme points is the same as finding the maximum (minimum) value of a function? I thought that to find extreme points one needed to use the definition: $x$ is extreme point of $S$ if $x=\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2$ implies $x=x_1=x_2$

Comment: @user441848 No for the question in your comment.  Extrema must occur at extreme points, but not vice versa.